# LWC does not load records for CustomProfile, but it does for SystemAdmin - I don't think it's Sharing, Global or FLS

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

System Admin loads records no problem

[image]

CustomProfile does not load records

[image]

As System Admin, this component loads records no problem, and ***data prints to console. When I switch to a CustomProfile, it does not load, and ***data does not print to console. I also have a debug statement in the Apex, and that only prints to log as System Admin, not CustomProfile.

I've gone through CustomProfile's OWD and FLS, but I'm happy to again. I've tried the Apex Controller with and without sharing already. I'm thinking there's something I don't understand about LWC still; I'm pretty new.

```
  @wire(getEventActivityWrappers, {siteSurveyId:'$siteSurveyId'}) 
    wiredGetEventActivityWrappers({data, error}) {
      if (data) {
        console.log('*** data: ',data);
        this.isSubmitted = data.isSubmitted;
        this.activities = data.eventActivityWrappers;
        if (this.activities) {
          this.activities.forEach((activity) => {
            if (activity.type == "Mandated Activity") {
              this.mandatedActivityCount += 1;
              this.mandatedActivities.push(activity);
            } else if (activity.type == "If Appropriate") {
              this.ifAppropriateActivities.push(activity); 
            } else if (activity.type == "Optional Activity") {
              this.optionalActivities.push(activity); 
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

---

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
  public static EventActivityChecklistWrapper getEventActivityWrappers(
    String siteSurveyId) {
    
    EventActivityChecklistWrapper checklistWrapper = 
      new EventActivityChecklistWrapper();
    List<EventActivityWrapper> eventActivityWrappers = 
      new List<EventActivityWrapper>();
    Site_Survey__c survey = [SELECT Id, 
                                    Risk_Tier__c,
                                    Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c, 
                                    Event_Activity_Checklist_isSubmitted__c
                             FROM Site_Survey__c 
                             WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];

    List<String> riskTierRange = buildRiskTierRange(survey.Risk_Tier__c);

    List<Event_Activity__c> eventActivities = [SELECT Id, Title__c, Type__c 
                                               FROM Event_Activity__c 
                                               WHERE Risk_Tier__c IN :riskTierRange
                                               ORDER BY Id ASC];

    checklistWrapper.isSubmitted = 
      survey.Event_Activity_Checklist_isSubmitted__c;
    checklistWrapper.eventActivityWrappers = 
      makeEventActivtityWrappersList(eventActivities, survey);
    System.debug('*** getEventActivityWrappers - checklistWrapper: '+ checklistWrapper);
    return checklistWrapper;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SFDC, went to Setup > Apex Classes > MyApex_Controller > Security
Only System Admin could access this class. After adding CustomProfile, that user now sees the records on the front end.